# How to use .format to insert list elements into a string and output multiple strings?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to insert elements from a list into a string, and output all the resulting strings.

Here is my list:

```
fruit = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana']
```

Here is my string:

```
my_string = The store is selling {}
```

I want my resulting strings to look like this:

```
The store is selling Apple
The store is selling Orange
The store is selling Mango
The store is selling Banana
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
i = 0
while i < len(fruit):
  i = i + 1
  new_strings = my_string.format(fruit[i - 1])
  print(new_strings)
```

This does print what I want (all resulting 4 strings) when print(new_strings) is inside the loop, but when I try to print(new_strings) outside of the while loop, it only prints the last string:

```
The store is selling Banana
```

How can I get print(new_strings) to print outside of the while loop? Is it a problem with my code? Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Assigning a new value to `new_strings` completely discards the previous value.  You'd need to append each string to a list, or perhaps some other sort of container, if you wanted them all to be available after the loop ends.

Comment: Re-reading the question, you only asked whether it's a problem with your code if it can only print the last fruit outside the loop. No, that's expected. `new_strings` is overridden on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use f-strings. They are easy to use and best practice!

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Banana"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print(f"The store is selling {fruit}")
```

Comment: They want to print all result strings outside the loop. They already know how to print inside the loop.

Comment: I don't get it. How would you print the message for every item without using a loop? This for-loop could be separate from the while loop, if that is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
fruit = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana']
strs = [f'The store is selling {x}' for x in fruit]
print(strs)

# or
for s in strs:
    print(s)
```

Comment: I think you need to change `print(s)` to `print(x)` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Following more closely your original approach try this code:

```
fruit = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana']

list_of_strings = []

for fruit in fruits:
    list_of_strings.append(f"The store is selling {fruit}")
    
print(list_of_strings)
```